# C#: How to translate nested structures from C to C#?

Tags: c#, c, class, struct, nested

I have a program written in C which contains some nested structures of arrays like the following:

```
typedef struct
{
    int s1var1[s1max1],
    float s1var2[s1max2];
}struct1;


typedef struct
{
    int s2var1[s2max1];
    struct1 s2var2[s2max2];
        *s2var2_ptr;
}struct2;
```

and I've written it in C# as following:

```
class Class1
{
    public int[] s1var1 = new int[s1max1];
    public float[] s1var2 = new float[s1max2];
}


class Class2
{
    public int[] s2var1 = new int[s2max1];
    public Class1[] s2var2 = new Class1[s2max2];
}
```

Is my translation true? What is wrong with this translation?

Thanks for your time.

Comment: Use struct in c#.  A structure in c is continuous data,   In c# a class has additional data beside the object (like the type).

Comment: @jdweng: That's the wrong criterion for deciding; the right criteria are: (1) is the type logically a value? (2) is the type logically immutable? (3) is the type small?  If the answer to all three questions is yes, use a struct. If not, use a class.

Comment: Majid, can you say a little bit more about what the purposes of these data structures are? We normally do not make types with public fields in C# whether they are structs or classes.

Comment: @Eric Lippert : You comment makes no sense.  The question are : Is my translation true? What is wrong with this translation?

Comment: @jdweng: My comment is entirely sensible; your advice to use a struct is premature. There is *plenty* wrong with the translation that was given. To know what the right translation is requires us to understand the usage cases for the types! There's no one "right" way to translate code from one language to another. **Programs express developer intent**, and so a proper translation *preserves intent*, not *memory layout*.

Comment: @jdweng, You mean class does not work as struct? I believed that struct can be a sub-set of class! Which property struct has and class does not have?

Comment: In C# `struct` means *copy by value* and `class` means *copy by reference*.  That is **completely different** than what `struct` and `class` mean in C++.  In C++, `struct` means "fields are public by default" and `class` means "fields are private by default".  **It is very important in C# to understand the difference between values and references**.

Comment: Also, it's often a bad idea to directly expose an array; arrays are mutable, but often the mutability is undesirable. Again, describe the *real* meaning of these types and how you expect them to be used in your C# program. Design the types around the use cases.

Comment: @Eric Lippert, Thanks for the comments, to propose some more details, let say, I have some populations of type struct2, each population has some properties. Each population consist of some individuals, s2var2. Each individual has some properties which are arrays with different sizes. I have to create such populations and make calculations (with some methods in other classes) based on them to create new populations. I wish this help.

Comment: @Eric Lippert, would you please describe what is wrong with making fields with public attribute? Or would you please refer me to any other page for clarification?

Comment: It will be difficult to teach you C# in a series of comments! If you want to learn C#, there are lots of good books on the subject. What is wrong with making fields public is: in C# we usually think of fields as private implementation details, and *properties* as being the public surface that exposes those fields, and determines who gets to read and write them.  C programming is about transparent data structures and procedures that manipulate them. C# programming is about opaque components that encapsulate functionality with data.

Comment: @Eric Lippert, as can be seen, in structures, I only have arrays and no method. And I want to work with this arrays, determine their value, use and update theme.

Comment: A structure is a structure and is the same whether it is in global space or inside a class.  This can be said of any object in c# that the size and organization does not change when moved to a different level of the program.

Answer (score 2):

```
public  struct struct1
{
    public int[] s1var1;
    public float[] s1var2;
}


public  struct struct2
{
    public int[] s2var1;
    public struct1[] s2var2;
}


public static void Main()
{   

        struct1 str;
        str.s1var1 = new int[10];
        str.s1var2= new float[10];

        //or
        struct1 str1 = new struct1();
        str1.s1var1 =  new int[10];
        str1.s1var2= new float[10];
        ////
     struct2 str2;
     str2.s2var1 = new int[10];
     str2.s2var2 = new struct1[10];

    }
```

> A struct type is a value type that is typically used to encapsulate
>   small groups of related variables, such as the coordinates of a
>   rectangle or the characteristics of an item in an inventory.
>
> When a struct is created, the variable to
>   which the struct is assigned holds the struct's actual data. When the
>   struct is assigned to a new variable, it is copied. The new variable
>   and the original variable therefore contain two separate copies of the
>   same data. Changes made to one copy do not affect the other copy.

[Microsoft source](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/struct)
[Learn More About Structs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/using-structs)
[Classes and Structs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/index)

Comment: Thanks, how can I create and initialize an object of a structure? Specially, in this case, which I have arrays in my structures!

Comment: struct2 str = new struct2();

Comment: thanks, suppose I have created struct2 str2 = new struct2(), how can I initialize str2.s2var2.s1var1[i] and how to determine array s1var1 size?

Comment: str2.s2var2 = new struct1[10];

Comment: Please, would you describe how can I pass a struct into a method without pointer in C# ?

Comment: I found this page about passing struct OR class variable to a method: [Know the Difference Between Passing a Struct and Passing a Class Reference to a Method (C# Programming Guide)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/how-to-know-the-difference-passing-a-struct-and-passing-a-class-to-a-method)

Answer (score 0):

First, let's take a look at your code conceptually. In C you have some structures and in C# you have some classes. You will need to know that [struct is different from class](https://blogs.mentor.com/colinwalls/blog/2014/06/02/struct-vs-class-in-c/) in many ways, not to mention that we have here some different languages as well, so writing a C# [struct](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/struct) would be more suitable. However, if we look at your implementation, we see that on declaration level you try to assign some values to your arrays respectively. Are you sure the limits you use are defined and visible at the point you attempt to use them? Also, it would be much better if you would use a constructor and initialize your arrays there. And finally, I'm not sure at the point of Class2 you see Class1 which you attempt to use.